# Create new table using data of existing table

Tags: mysql

using below mentioned code but getting cross sign  stating wrong syntax

```
create table bajaj1 as (
    select `Date`, `ClosePrice`
        row_number() over(order by `Date` as `Row_num`,
        Avg(`ClosePrice`) over(order by `Date` rows 19 preceding) as `20 Day MA`,
        Avg(`ClosePrice`) over(order by `Date` rows 49 preceding) as `20 Day MA`
    from `bajaj auto`
);
```

**here creating new table "bajaj1' using date and closePrice of table "bajaj auto". Using mySql-8.0.13 version**

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  There is a missing commas after `ClosePrice`.

Comment: Also appears to be a missing `)` after `row_number() over (order by \`Date\``

Comment: You need MySQL 8.0 to use window functions.